# htaccess redirecting old urls

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on my htaccess and I finally got a result I can deal with. First I've got this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1article_title=$2 [L]
```

This helps show my urls like so:

```
https://www.mydomain.com/blog.php?id=10
```

To

```
https://www.mydomain.com/blog/10/title.com
https://www.mydomain.com/blog/10/
https://www.mydomain.com/blog/10
https://www.mydomain.com/blog/10/title.com/
```

**Four things here...**

First is that all of these are accessible. I only want the first to appear and the others to direct there.

Second is that the article title will have spaces. Is there a way to turn spaces into - rather than have spaces?

Third is...is it okay to have .com within the url at the end? It just happens to be part of a post article title.
Fourth is do I include the extra part of the url$article_title in the urls I use? I'm lost on that part. Is it the same as I did with the id?

Last I was curious to know if I needed the id to show up. Can I exclude that in some way?

If I have urls already in place that use blog.php?id=10 do I change that to the new one? If I can't find it I'd like the url to go to the first rewritten url. All of the possible examples should go to that first url. or one without the id.

Comment: You have $1 and $2 in your URL, but only one group in brackets. It is not right.

Comment: @user4035 thanks for the info...do you mean blog.php?id=10article_title=the title?

Comment: Your rule should look as follows: `RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&article_title=$2 [L]` or even `RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/([\w\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&article_title=$2 [L]`

Comment: thanks @MikeAnthony I see what you mean, but I still dont understand how to handle the old url. If i go to `blog.php?id=10&article_title=thetitle` this is still a valid url. How do I make that become the desired url?